# Inserting an llvm intrinsic in LLVM IR

Tags: llvm

I am trying to insert a custom defined intrinsic (int_x86_addenc_32) in llvm which is defined in IntrinsicsX86.td. Can someone help me with the code of calling such an intrinsic. (Intrinsic::getDeclaration(???))

On including Intrinsics.h,
I get an error saying ‘int_x86_addenc_32’ is not a member of ‘llvm::Intrinsic’.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!